# How to know if current pin code of certificate is valid

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'm using Delphi with SecureBlackBox to sign documents. I need to know if current PIN lifetime (PIN previous inputed) of selected certificate is valid, to know if the PIN UI will be shown. Is that possible, using winapi or SecureBlackBox directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem passing [CRYPT_SILENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptacquirecontexta#CRYPT_SILENT) flag to CryptAcquireContext function in secure black box code. This way the code will fail if pin has expired, instead of showing the pin UI.

Comment: Hi @Rodrigo Caetano, thanks for sharing the root cause and the solution, you could also feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).